# How to plot unit square using single matrix, to apply transformation matrices onto it

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to make a live script that demonstrates the effect of transformation matrices by showing its affect on the plotted unit square. Is it possible to plot a unit square using just a single matrix, such that transformation matrices can be applied to it and reflected in the plot?

I am able to plot a unit square using x and y row vectors but not together. I am unsure if plot() is even the best way to go about this, any help would be appreciate it.

```
A = [0 0 1 1 0; 
     0 1 1 0 0]
plot(A)

x = [0 0 1 1 0] 
y = [0 1 1 0 0]
plot(x,y)
```

The top portion of code is how I expected to have this work, the bottom portion is a successful plot of a unit square, but using two row vectors instead of a single matrix.

Comment: You can also do `plot(A(1,:),A(2,:))`. Read the `plot` documentation for what is happening in the first case.

Comment: This worked for my purposes! Thank you!